# Request for review of memory orders of mpsc queue

Tags: c++, thread-safety, memory-barriers, memory-model, stdatomic

I converted the C code of http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues/intrusive-mpsc-node-based-queue to C++.

At the time of writing this looks as follows:

```
struct MpscNode
{
  std::atomic<MpscNode*> m_next;
};

class MpscQueue
{
 private:
  std::atomic<MpscNode*> m_head;
  MpscNode*              m_tail;
  MpscNode               m_stub;

 public:
  MpscQueue() : m_head(&m_stub), m_tail(&m_stub), m_stub{{nullptr}} { }

  void push(MpscNode* node)
  {
    node->m_next.store(nullptr, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    MpscNode* prev = m_head.exchange(node, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    prev->m_next.store(node, std::memory_order_release);
  }

  MpscNode* pop()
  {
    MpscNode* tail = m_tail;
    MpscNode* next = tail->m_next.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if (tail == &m_stub)
    {
      if (nullptr == next)
        return nullptr;
      m_tail = next;
      tail = next;
      next = next->m_next.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    }
    if (next)
    {
      m_tail = next;
      return tail;
    }
    MpscNode* head = m_head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if (tail != head)
      return nullptr;
    push(&m_stub);
    next = tail->m_next.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if (next)
    {
      // Remove node and return it.
      m_tail = next;
      return tail;
    }
    return nullptr;
  }
};
```

You can see the latest version, including my comments, here: https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/threading/MpscQueue.h

My question is about the second line in `push`:

```
MpscNode* prev = m_head.exchange(node, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

I do not feel entirely sure about the memory order used here.
It seems right, but I'd like a review of the memory orders that I used.

I can't test it, because I only have an Intel CPU - not one with weak
atomic (like -say- ARM).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @avh I beg to differ, because this is not really a request to review code. The question is about the correct use of, and therefore the meaning of, memory orders. A highly specialistic technical subject. Furthermore, this is such a well-known (general) algorithm that it will benefit a lot of people to know what the right memory orders to use are (the original design lacking them).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your code is correct! The operations on `m_head` can be relaxed, because they are not used for any synchronization. `pop` only loads `m_head` to check if it equals tail, but there are not operations that depend on a synchronize-with relation on `m_head`.

The important operations are on `m_next` which is used to establish the necessary synchronization, and there your correctly use acquire/release orders.

So from my perspective this code looks fine!

FWIW: you don't necessarily need a CPU with a weak memory model to detect data races; thread-sanitizer does a pretty good job on x86 CPUs too.

---

**Edit:**

Let me try to elaborate... First of all, let's note some general observations.

1. The queue always holds at least one node, i.e., `m_tail` and `m_head` always point to some node and are never null.
2. The queue is empty if and only if `m_tail` and `m_head` point to `m_stub`. If `m_tail` and `m_head` both point to some node that is not `m_stub`, the queue contains one element (namely that node), so we have to push `m_stub` in order to be enable to dequeue that node and satisfay our requirement that the queue always holds at least one node.
3. The queue is not linearizable!

When reasoning about memory orders we first need to identify our requirements, i.e., what are the necessary happens-before relations. Let's use the following notation:

```
happens-before    -hb->
synchronize-with  -sw->
sequenced-before  -sb->
read-from         -rf->
```

In this case it is simple - we need a happens-before relation between the push and pop operations. In particular we need to show the following (`node1` and `node2` are separate variables, but both point to the same node; `init` and `consume` are some arbitrary functions that operate on the node):

```
init(node1) -sb-> push(node1) -hb-> node2 = pop() -sb-> consume(node2)
```

Due to the transitivity of the happens-before relation it follows that `init(node1) -hb-> consume(node2)`. So how can we ensure that? Let's look at the `push` operation:

```
node->m_next.store() -sb-> m_head.exchange() -sb-> prev-m_next.store()
```

The store to `prev->m_next` is our synchronization point. The node can only be consume once this store becomes visible to the consumer.

Now let's look at the `pop` operation. First of all, we can note that there are two paths that do not return a `nullptr`, and both of these paths return the variable `tail`. There are two assignments to `tail`, one from `m_tail` and one from `next` if `tail == &m_stub`. We will ignore the latter case here since it is easy to formulate similar arguments. `m_tail` cannot be used to establish an inter-thread-happens-before relation with `pop`, so we have to consider how `m_tail` receives its value.

There are two assignments to `m_tail` (we keep ignoring the `tail == &m_stub` case), both assigning `next` which itself is assigned the result of `tail->m_next.load()`. So we end up with the following (simplified):

```
                         pop_1                                        pop_2
v-------------------------^---------------------v    v-----------------^----------------v
next=tail->m_next.load() -sb-> m_tail=next -sb-> ... -sb-> tail=m_tail -sb-> return tail

Note: pop_1 is the pop call preceeding pop_2.
```

This code path contains only a single atomic operation - the load of `tail->m_next` - so this operation has to establish the necessary happens-before relation. This is achieved by using acquire/release orders. If the load in the `pop` operation observes the value written by the store in `push`, then these two operations establish a synchronize-with relation. It is worth noting that the inter-thread-happens-before relation required by `pop_2` is actually established by `pop_1`:

```
                thread1                                      thread2
  v----------------^-------------v     v------------------------^---------------------v
   prev->m_next.store(mo_release) -rf-> next=tail->m_next.load(mo_acquire) -sb-> pop_2
=> prev->m_next.store(mo_release) -sw-> next=tail->m_next.load(mo_acquire) -sb-> pop_2
=> prev->m_next.store(mo_release) -hb-> next=tail->m_next.load(mo_acquire) -sb-> pop_2
=>                           push -hb-> pop_2
```

Now let's look at the code path that performs a load of `m_head`. First, this path is only relevant if `next` is null. Second, if `m_head` is *different* from `tail`, we immediately return with a nullptr (this can happen if a `push` has performed the exchange, but not yet the store to `m_next` - recall, this queue is not linearizable).
So we only continue if `m_head` is equal to `tail` (i.e., that is the case were we have a single node left in the queue that is not `m_stub`), but we just discussed how we have already established the necessary happens-before relation for `tail`, so we don't need `m_head` for that!
And if there is no acquire-operation on `m_head` there is no point in using `memory_order_release` for the exchange operation, because there is nothing that would synchronize-with that exchange.

Comment: Thanks. I came to the same conclusion with a slightly longer argumentation (see my comments in https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/threading/MpscQueue.h). Nevertheless, I still felt insecure after that. And your reasoning isn't really adding to my own, so I'm still not convinced ;). I guess the only way that I'd be 100% convinced is when it is WRONG and someone gave a counter example showing how it could go wrong; or when the code in analysed with tool showing that it is correct. I have used such a tool before, but it is never very clear how to write the test to cover everything.

Comment: @CarloWood I have edited my answer to provide a more elaborate discussion with arguments about why acquire/release for the operations on `m_next` are _necessary_ and _sufficient_. Let me know if you are still not convinced, and if so, why. :)